# Hammering pipes

Tags: plumbing

I have pipes hammering in the walls. I happens when other water flows are shut off such as a toilet finished filling up or water shutting off when washer fills up. This is only on cold water. I blocked the water supply to the spare bathroom shower/tub and the hammering stopped. Could the cartridge be bad? The water pressure inside the house is around 100psi.

Answer (score 1):

First of all 100 PSI is far too high in a home. High pressure can cause leaks and damaged plumbing connections especially when you're turning the main shutoff valve back on. So be sure to turn it on **slowly**. Then you need to have the pressure adjusted on the pressure reduction valve which should be on the main line coming into the house somewhere around your shutoff. Your water pressure should not be higher than about 65 PSI. If the PRV is old and corroded, like mine is right now, you might want to just replace it.
Now to get to your question. Hammering pipes could be caused by a number of things but the most frequent culprit I have found is a shower cartridge that needs to be replaced. They build up corrosion over time that impedes smooth water flow. If the hammering only occurs when you turn on the cold side in your shower and it sounds like that's the case - replace the cartridge on the cold water side.

Answer (score 0):

You could add water hammer "shock absorbers" , an air cushion chamber. Those I have seen for 1/2 and 3/4 copper pipe are copper about 1.5 " diameter about a foot long, like a bottle. They are mounted vertically ( open end down ) near the valves that cause the banging.  I wanted to add some at the washer when the house was built but the location was too inconvenient/expensive to add them , turns out we did not need them.

Comment: I went to get a water hammer dampener for my dishwasher at a local plumbing store.  The guys there said instead of a hard copper pipe connection, use a braided hose connection so the vibration isn't transmitted.   It worked!